# Using lead/lag with multiple variables in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My objective is to use `data.table` to count the number of bikes that have left a station, and then to aggregate by `station_id`, `hour`, and `date`.

If the previous record - current record of `bikes_available` is positive, then that is the amount of bikes lost.  If the previous record - current record is negative or zero, then that means the number of bikes has stayed the same or increased, so these cases should not be counted.

```
> head(dat, n = 10)
    station_id bikes_available                time       date hour
 1:          3               2 2018-01-15 01:58:02 2018-01-15    1
 2:          3               1 2018-01-15 01:59:01 2018-01-15    1
 3:          3               1 2018-01-15 02:00:03 2018-01-15    2
 4:          3               4 2018-01-15 02:01:02 2018-01-15    2
 5:          3               4 2018-01-15 02:02:02 2018-01-15    2
 6:          3               1 2018-01-15 02:03:02 2018-01-15    2
 7:          3               1 2018-01-15 02:04:02 2018-01-15    2
 8:          3               1 2018-01-15 02:05:02 2018-01-15    2
 9:          3               7 2018-01-15 02:06:02 2018-01-15    2
10:          3               3 2018-01-15 02:07:02 2018-01-15    2
```

The `lead` function can be used to find the difference between the previous and current record and then only positive values filtered out with:

```
dat[,ba_lead:=shift(bikes_available, 1, type='lead')]
dat$diff <- dat$bikes_available - dat$ba_lead
```

But how would one then group by 3 variables -  `station_id` `time` and `date` using `data.table`?

For example, the following output would be expected from the data provided

```
> output
  station_id bikes_taken hour       date
1          3           1    1 2018-01-15
2          3           7    2 2018-01-15
3          4           4    1 2018-01-15
4          4           1    2 2018-01-15
5          5           0    1 2018-01-15
6          5           2    2 2018-01-15
```

(full dataset below)

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(station_id = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), bikes_available = c(2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 7, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 3), time = structure(c(1516010282, 1516010341, 1516010403, 
1516010462, 1516010522, 1516010582, 1516010642, 1516010702, 1516010762, 
1516010822, 1516010282, 1516010341, 1516010403, 1516010462, 1516010522, 
1516010582, 1516010642, 1516010702, 1516010762, 1516010822, 1516010282, 
1516010341, 1516010403, 1516010462, 1516010522, 1516010582, 1516010642, 
1516010702, 1516010762, 1516010822), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), date = structure(c(17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 
17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 
17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 
17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546, 17546), class = "Date"), 
    hour = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("station_id", "bikes_available", 
"time", "date", "hour"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102800778>)
```

Comment: Since you're aggregating by the hour, why are you using the `lead` function? why not just take the final value for the hour or the max value for the hour?

Comment: because you must use lead to see the difference between the minute intervals - it's not about the final value.  Many bikes could have been taken if the final value for the hour is 0.  Also, zero bikes could have been taken if the final value for the hour is 10

Comment: ah, alright. thanks for the clarification. makes sense now... i was reading it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tidyverse` functions, you can try :

```
df %>%
  group_by(station_id, date, hour) %>%
  mutate( b_taken = bikes_available - lead(bikes_available)) %>%
  filter(b_taken >= 0) %>%
  mutate(b_taken = sum(b_taken)) %>%
  select(b_taken) %>%
  unique()
```

which gives:

```
  station_id       date  hour b_taken
       <int>     <date> <int>   <dbl>
1          3 2018-01-15     1       1
2          3 2018-01-15     2       7
3          4 2018-01-15     1       4
4          4 2018-01-15     2       1
5          5 2018-01-15     1       0
6          5 2018-01-15     2       2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library("data.table")
setDT(dat)
dat[, 
    j = .(bikes_taken = bikes_available - shift( x = bikes_available, n = 1, type = 'lead')),
    by = .(station_id, date, hour)][ i = bikes_taken >= 0, 
                                     j = .(bikes_taken = sum(bikes_taken)), 
                                     by = .(station_id, date, hour)]

#    station_id       date hour bikes_taken
# 1:          3 2018-01-15    1           1
# 2:          3 2018-01-15    2           7
# 3:          4 2018-01-15    1           4
# 4:          4 2018-01-15    2           1
# 5:          5 2018-01-15    1           0
# 6:          5 2018-01-15    2           2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take with `data.table`:

```
dat[, .(bikes_taken = diff(bikes_available)), by = .(station_id, date, hour)
    ][bikes_taken <= 0, .(bikes_taken = sum(bikes_taken*-1)), by = .(station_id, date, hour)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    station_id       date hour bikes_taken
> 1:          3 2018-01-15    1           1
> 2:          3 2018-01-15    2           7
> 3:          4 2018-01-15    1           4
> 4:          4 2018-01-15    2           1
> 5:          5 2018-01-15    1           0
> 6:          5 2018-01-15    2           2
> ```